# PHP - Ajax not working on Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

**$_GET['cat']** varialble can be passed in IE and Moz. But Chrome passes as empty string. How can this be? #accordion div is in content php and written by the first load function. In Chrome, the code can load accordion.php successfully because I can see there are some valid parts written in #accordion div. But not passing variable:

```
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script>
    $("#content").load("content.php?tv=true&uniq="+$.now(), function() {
      $.ajax({url: "accordion.php?cat=<?php echo $_GET['cat']; ?>&uniq="+$.now(),
             success: function(html) {
               $("#accordion").html(html);
             }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: It might help you to wrap your jQuery code in `$(document).ready(function(){...` so it is evaluated when the DOM is ready...

Comment: I tried that actually. It didn't help. I think there is no problem with getting document ready because some parts of _#accordion_ is being written successfully. EDIT: I tried it anyway, didn't work again.

Comment: What page source is being generated, exactly? In Chrome, look at the page source, and see what exactly is in your <script> tag; specifically, when `$_GET['cat']` is interpolated, what is the url property?

Comment: The script is generated as `$("#content").load("content.php?tv=true&uniq="+$.now(), function() {
$.ajax({url: "accordion.php?cat=Movie&uniq="+$.now(), success: function(html) {$("#accordion").css("display","none");$("#accordion").html(html);}});});`
which is totally correct...

Comment: Should I use session? Does it worth to spend time?

Comment: What happens if you hard code `Movie` for cat instead of echoing from PHP?

Comment: Good try! It worked...then..what does it mean?

Comment: I found the guilty! All the browsers sends the code for once. But, Chrome sends twice and...guess what, second goes empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for missing information in the question.
I had a include php at the beginning. I didn't think that was affecting.
Here is the solution:

```
<?php if($_GET['rel']!='tab') {
    include 'header.php';
    echo '<div id="content"></div>';
        echo '<script>var category="'.$_GET['cat'].'";</script>';
} 
?>
<script>
$("body").animate({ backgroundColor: "#00973A" }, 1000);
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "content.php?tv=true&uniq="+$.now(), success: function(html) {$("#content").html(html);}});
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "accordion.php?cat="+category+"&uniq="+$.now(), success: function(html) {$("#accordion").html(html);}});});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems something is happening in the echoing via php so you'll need to implement some debugging. I'd recomend something like the following

```
<?php 
    $category = "Movie";
    echo "<!-- " . $category . "-->" #check the HTML source and see if you get "Movie"
?>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  $("#content").load("content.php?tv=true&uniq="+$.now(), function() {
    $.ajax({url: "accordion.php?cat=<?php echo $category; ?>&uniq="+$.now(),
           success: function(html) {
             $("#accordion").html(html);
           }
    });
  });
</script>
```

If that works you know the basics are now working. Then try the following in the PHP block

```
<?php 
    $category = $_GET['cat'];
    echo "<!-- " . $category . "-->" #check the HTML source and see if you get a value
?>
```

This will tell you if you're getting the `cat` value correctly.

**Note** my php is a little rusty so my concatentation operaters and comment delimiters may be wrong!

Comment: Did hardcoding the PHP variable work? If not did you check the HTML as rendered to see if the debug HTML comment was rendered there;

Comment: What did you see for the debug HTML comment when assiging `$_GET['cat']` to the php variable?

Comment: I don't know how to debug HTML comment in Chrome.

Comment: Right click anywhere on the page and select "View Page Source" and look for the comment `<!-- -->` on the page. Contained in there will be what was retrieved for $_GET['cat']. Also look over this: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Aaah, I see. I wrote on a comment at the first post. It echoes correctly. It can't pass...

Comment: Also this works:`<?php echo '<script>$("#content").load("content.php?tv=true&uniq="+$.now(), function() {
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "accordion.php?cat=Movie&uniq="+$.now(), success: function(html) {$("#accordion").html(html);}});});
</script>'
?>`

But this doesn't: `<?php echo '<script>$("#content").load("content.php?tv=true&uniq="+$.now(), function() {
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "accordion.php?cat='.$_GET['cat'].'&uniq="+$.now(), success: function(html) {$("#accordion").html(html);}});});
</script>'
?>`

Comment: I don't know how browsers work exactly but it smells like it's a caching problem. I tried to re-install Chrome and it worked correctly on the first send. Then malfunctioned again.

Comment: I found the guilty! All the browsers sends the code for once. But, Chrome sends twice and...guess what, second goes empty!